# catkin_make and catkin_tools not finding new msg/srv?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I add a new `.msg` (I confirmed for `.srv` as well) and running `catkin build`, the new file doesn't seem to be processed.
Is this expected, or is there a way to let it find new definition? This <s>doesn't seem to be</s> is also a case with `catkin_make`.

```
CWS_PROOV=/tmp/cws_proof
mkdir -p "$CWS_PROOV"/src
cd "$CWS_PROOV"/src
git clone git@github.com:130s/prooving_grounds.git        <-- Merely beginner_tutorials with minor change
cd "$CWS_PROOV"
catkin b
ll ./devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg
source devel/setup.bash 
roscd beginner_tutorials/
echo "int64 num" > msg/Num4.msg
cd -
catkin b
ll ./devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg
total 24K
drwxrwxr-x 2 rosnoodle rosnoodle 4.0K Mar 17 14:23 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 rosnoodle rosnoodle 4.0K Mar 17 14:23 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rosnoodle rosnoodle  111 Mar 17 14:23 __init__.py -> /tmp/cws_proof/devel/.private/beginner_tutorials/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/__init__.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rosnoodle rosnoodle  108 Mar 17 14:23 _Num2.py -> /tmp/cws_proof/devel/.private/beginner_tutorials/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/_Num2.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rosnoodle rosnoodle  108 Mar 17 14:23 _Num3.py -> /tmp/cws_proof/devel/.private/beginner_tutorials/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/_Num3.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rosnoodle rosnoodle  107 Mar 17 14:23 _Num.py -> /tmp/cws_proof/devel/.private/beginner_tutorials/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/_Num.py
ll /tmp/cws_proof/devel/.private/beginner_tutorials/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg
    (Num4 not found)
ll ./devel/share/gennodejs/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg
    (Num4 not found)
ll ./devel/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg
    (Num4 not found)

$ apt-cache policy python-catkin-tools|grep Inst
  Installed: 0.4.4-1
```

To work this around I'm removing `build`, `devel` before building. After modifying `CMakeLists.txt` also works for me.
Seen on Xenial Kinetic and Trusty Indigo.

---

UPDATE After listing all `.msg`s and `.srv`s in CMakeLists.txt both `catkin_make` and `catkin build` seem to find the new files and update to the existing files. It'd be still nice if there's a way to achieve the same without listing them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257293/catkin_make-and-catkin_tools-not-finding-new-msg/srv?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-18**:\

> ```
> echo "int64 num" > msg/Num4.msg
> ```

just making sure: you did add `Num4.msg` to the `add_message_files(..)` call in `CMakeLists.txt`, correct?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-18**:
Nope, only passing `DIRECTORY` ([exact line in my sample](https://goo.gl/ksfvyp)). Thanks to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/212420/messages-from-subfolders/) (aka yours :)) I've been able to build msgs without specifing `FILES`. But added files aren't the case, which is my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As documented by CMake (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/file.html):

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

If you glob the files instead of listing them explicitly CMake has no way of knowing when it needs to reconfigure. Therefore you should list them explicitly. Otherwise you need to force the CMake invocation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-20**:
Yeah. That's basically what I wrote in the answer to #q212420 that @130s referenced ;)